# Capturing groups and lookarounds

Tags: python, regex

I want to know how capturing groups (or non capturing) are affecting lookarounds in Regex.
Here are 2 example:

```
test (?:(?!<start).)+

test (?!<start).+
```

I would appreciate if anybody can explain how regex engine is interpreting both cases in details.

Comment: With what language are you using the regex?

Comment: Does it really matter? I thought Regex acts same way in all langauges. Python.

Comment: Every language has it's own documentation and engine.

Answer (score 3):

1. Look-arounds are [zero-width](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In that respect, it doesn't make much sense to place them on their own inside a capturing group, they don't capture anything more interesting than an empty string (much like `\b vs. (\b)`. <sub><sup>Edge cases involve back-referencing an optional group, but that isn't very interesting.</sup></sub>
2. Positive looharounds - `(?=...)` and `(?<=...)` - can capture groups. For example, `/(?=(\b\w+\b))/` will result in positive *empty* matches, where each match has a non-empty group. For example, `/(?<=(.))\1/` will match characters that follow identical characters.
3. Negative looharounds - `(?!...)` and `(?<!...)` - cannot capture groups. That makes a lot of sense when you think about it, because the *never match*, but they can use capturing groups within them. For example, `^(?!.*(.).*\1).*$` will match a line that does not contain duplicated letters.  <sub><sup>Again, how `\1` behaves, in that case, out of the group is not particularity interesting.</sup></sub>

Now, to your example. The two patterns match different texts:

1. `(?:(?!<start).)+` - Check we are not after the text `start`, and then match all characters (of the line). Examples:

   1. Input `"start1234end"`, matches the *whole input* - the *start position* isn't after the word "start".
   2. Input `"before123startAfter"` Suppose the previous match was `"before123start"` (on a different pattern the allows that), the next match cannot start here, and will skip one character: `"fter"`.
2. `(?:(?!<start).)+` - Here, the lookbehind assertion is **repeated for every character** (for intuition: if a group `(?:...)+` is a loop, the assertion is *inside the loop*). A character will not be matched if it is directly *after* the string `start`:

   1. Input `"start1234end"` - First match will be `"start"`. The engine cannot match the next `'1'` (because it isn't a character that isn't after `start`), so the match stops. The next match will be `"234end"`.

Comment: I think the example is not lookbehind assertion but lookahead. Also what exactly defines a loop within non-capturing or capturing group? That's the key part I want to understand.

Comment: @Michael is right: `(?!<start)` is a negative **lookahead** for `<start`.  You're thinking of `(?<!start)`, a negative *lookbehind* for `start`.